# Why does this compile when the return type is incorrect?

Tags: c#, async-await

The function returns a `HttpResponseMessage`, which is an object. But its not returning a `Task`. And yet it compiles.

```
public async Task<object> Item()
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "There was a validation error");
}
```

Comment: It *is* returning a task.  I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: Request.CreateErrorResponse returns a HttpResponseMessage. Which is not a Task.

Comment: Your method is defined as an asynchoronus  task and its return type is object

Comment: Yes, but I'm not returning a Task.

Comment: @FeryalBadili No, the return type of the method is `Task<object>`.

Comment: @IanWarburton -- the compiler knows the method is `async` so it automatically wraps your object in a `Task<object>`.  Is that what you're wondering about?

Comment: @rory.ap I guess so.

Comment: @Servy: Nope. Please read the answer that yo uhave marked for this question. The 'task' returns and 'object'

Comment: @IanWarburton -- It's compiler magic.  That's all.

Comment: @FeryalBadili The type of the expression of the return statement needs to be `object`, but the return type of the method is `Task<object>`, you can see as much by looking at the signature of the method.  The return type of the method is *not* `object`.

Comment: @rory.ap There's a duplicate question with an answer.

Comment: Here's a good explanation and example of this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt674893.aspx#Task Return Type

Comment: @Servy -- Weird, usually my browser automatically tells me the question was closed.  Didn't happen this time.  Refreshed, ok.

Comment: @Servy: How do explain this line from the answer that you have marked for this question? "return 42;//Note we return int not Task<int> and that compiles"

Comment: @FeryalBadili By reading the rest of the answer...it explains that line.